# Uploading Excel Files in to Sharepoint List

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer

There is a custom list with students' identification numbers, branches will update the student applications in particular SharePoint list. all applications are processing at centralized unit. branch staff needs to check the status of such applications.

Centralized staff have to update each item in the sharepoint list. can we update specific amount of applications at one time by uploading excel file in to that sharepoint list. is there a option ?

Comment: Did you try copy paste from excel to your SharePoint List in Quick edit mode ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Karthik's method, you can try to copy the data in excel directly and paste it into the list in a quick edit mode.

[image]

In addition, set up the same column in the list as in excel files.

[image]

Comment: how to map such applications in Share point, I have to filter one by one and then paste

Comment: If the number of files is large, it is recommended to refer to the synchronization method provided by Karthikeyan

Answer (score 0):

**Approach 1:**

Using two-way synchronization, we can achieve the requirement. I have shared below the reference link

**Ref:** https://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com/product-documentation/

**Approach 2 :**

1. Add additional column to list and hide it into the view.
2. Export the list to excel(Click Refresh All to get recent data).
3. Please update the excel where you want
4. Build Powershell and use PS to push the updated values into list based upon additional column.

**Note:** Periodically schedule the PS/ Run PS manually

**Ref :** https://support.office.com/en-us/article/export-to-excel-from-sharepoint-bfb2ea48-6118-4fa9-abb6-cced9424e5d9